# Handle the selected items in list items

Tags: c#, wpf

in WPF, the list items contains some of items, when an item in `list items` is selected, i need to handle some of event on the selected item

after create a method that get the selected item

```
 private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string y = this.LBOX.SelectedItem.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(y);
    }
```

this method show : `System.Windows.Control.ListBoxItem.List1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are storing strings in your `ListBoxItems`, the `SelectedItem` property is actually returning an object that you need to cast to a `ListBoxItem` so that you can access the `Content` Property and then use the `ToString` Method on it. Something like this should work for you.

```
string y = ((ListBoxItem)LBOX.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast SelectedItem
Say you have the following

```
class Items
{
    string Name {get; set; }
    string Address { get; set; }
}
```

you have that assigned to your control.
To access those values you need to do this

```
//check that we have an item selected
//then check if item is of type Items, if not the cast below will error
if (LBOX.SelectedItem != null && LBOX.SelectedItem is Items)
{
    Items selectedItem = LBOX.SelectedItem as Items;
}
```